# Isometric Object reflection in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, isometric, reflection

How can I create a reflection for an isometric object?

in example image "N" letter is flat object with reflection i need similar reflection for my isometric cube.
[image: Flat object reflection]

Answer (score 5):

- Move it vertically down holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> to duplicate
- Send it back
- Reduce the opacity
- Add a Transparency Mask with a rectangle filled with a gradient from black at the bottom to white at the top

[image: cube]

[image]

Comment: This must be the simplest way to do it, but there is a problem with the gradient. It should follow the shape of the object. The reflection of the nearest corner gets too light. Also, if the object was more complex, you wouldn't be able to do this - you would have to redraw it seen from the bottom.

Comment: @Wolff well its not 3d so yes thet would be the downside

Comment: The Opacity mask can be adjusted to accommodate more of a "distance" gradient/fade rather than a standard, straight, linear gradient.